# Python selenium unable to fill input box by ID or xpath

Tags: selenium, python-3.8

I have the following code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait, Select
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

if __name__ == '__main__':
    path_to_chromedriver = r'C:\chromedriver'  # change path as needed
    browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=path_to_chromedriver)
    wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 10)
    browser.get("https://pjm.com/")
    wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "/html/body/form/div[3]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/span[2]"))).click()
    wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "IDToken1"))).send_keys("user")
    wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "IDToken2"))).send_keys("pwd")
```

But the last two lines of codes are not able to execute and I don't have a clue why it should be like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that the `click()` will open a new tab, in which case you have to switch to that tab before proceeding with login details:

```
browser.switch_to.window(browser.window_handles[1])
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "IDToken1"))).send_keys("user")
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "IDToken2"))).send_keys("pwd")
```